# ROS Answers SE migration: DIN-USB cable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

i'm new on ROS platform, and i'm buying roomba 500 series in order to try ROS.
now i'm checking where can i buy the DIN-USB cable.

can anyone help me?

thank you
Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243928/din-usb-cable/) by [ThomasPittin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27942/thomaspittin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to avoid assembling your own cable, you can buy one [directly from iRobot](http://store.irobot.com/default/parts-and-accessories/create-accessories/communication-cable-for-create-2/4466502.html). I am not aware of other options, but I'd be interested to know. This will allow you to communicate to the Roomba from a computer.
However, if you are interested in powering devices from the Roomba's battery you can see my [answer here](http://answers.ros.org/question/236239/how-can-i-power-a-kinect-using-the-irobot-create-2-base-turtlebot/?answer=236251#post-id-236251) about making your own.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0